# How to install FLTK on windows?

Tags: c++, powershell, visual-studio-code, chocolatey, fltk

I am trying to install FLTK but everytime I get this error and can't find the appropriate solution to it. I have chocolatey and make installed.

```
PS D:\My C & C++ programs\C++ programs\FLTK\fltk-1.3.6> make
if test -f config.status; then \
        ./config.status --recheck; \
        ./config.status; \
else \
        ./configure; \
fi
-f was unexpected at this time.
Makefile:17: makeinclude: No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:95: makeinclude] Error 255
```

Answer (score 0):

FLTK uses CMake as a build system generator. The makefile is just a convenience for calling configure (part of autotools which have limited support on Windows*). Similarly, make has limited support on Windows*.
To build, you need to install CMake then run:

```
cmake -B bin -S .
cmake --build bin
```

This will output the libraries in a newly created bin folder. The actual structure depends on the whether CMake used the visual studio build tools (default and need to be already installed) or another build system like nmake or ninja (which you can specify using the -G Ninja or -G NMake (to the first command)).

- If you would like to use configure and (gnu) make, you can do so in a posix emulation layer using something like msys2.